# Gradient of broadcast plus

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, machine-learning

Assume $$f(\vec b)=WX\,\tilde{+}\,b$$
where $W$ and $X$ are two matrices, $\vec b$ is a vector, and $\tilde{+}$ symbol is so-called *broadcast* plus:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}  \tilde{+}
 \begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
6 
\end{pmatrix}  
=  \begin{pmatrix}
6 & 7 \\
9 & 10 
\end{pmatrix}  
$$

How to calculate the gradient matrix of $f(\vec b)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you can replace the broadcast operation by adding the matrix

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}b & b & \dots & b \end{bmatrix}.$$

the gradient of the matrix-valued function $f$ with respect to $b$ is given by

$$\dfrac {\partial f_i}{\partial b_j} = \begin{bmatrix}\delta_{ij}&\delta_{ij}&\ldots &\delta_{ij} \end{bmatrix}.$$

In which $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ if $i\neq j$.

Comment: But what I want actually the gradient of vector $b$, not the matrix $B$. The result is supposed to be a *1-d vector*. In your case, I want to know the gradient of $g(b)=\begin{bmatrix}b & b & \dots & b \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

"Broadcasting plus" can be rewritten as matrix multiplication:

$$f(\vec b)=WX\,\tilde{+}\,Mb^\top$$ where $M = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\\vdots \\1 \end{bmatrix}$ is an $N\times 1$ matrix, and $b^\top$ is a $1\times N$ matrix.

Then, broadcasting $Mb^\top$ becomes literally the same thing as gradient of the normal matrix multiplication $WX$, so the gradient of $f$ over $b^\top$ will be equal to $M$.   When used in backpropagation, this will require you to multiply by $M^\top$ or $M$, which gives:

$$\frac{\partial Loss}{\partial b} = \frac{\partial Loss}{\partial f}M $$

This operation will likely **simply sum the gradients in each column**.  The exact notation depends on the task at hand, since you're taking a gradient of a matrix-valued function.

I've also just written a [lengthy post on this on my blog](http://coldattic.info/post/116/).